# jquery .click only works when button is placed outside all div tags

Tags: jquery, html

I'm trying to make a simple jquery toggle work. It's surprisingly complicated.

This is my script, I placed it in the head of the document.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        $("#abc").toggle();
    });
});
```

If I place the button anywhere but right after the `<body>` tag (like inside another div), nothing happens on click.

```
<button>Click me</button>
```

jquery is loading properly (according to console).

I have everything inside `document.ready`
and there is a `div` with the `id="abc"` in my html file.

what's wrong?

i put the whole code in this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/v97e8o5e/
and it works. 
it still doesn't in mozilla on localhost/ (ubuntu server).

Comment: As per above code, It should work

Comment: You'll need to post more code, your code so far is valid.

Comment: Here's a working fiddle using exactly the code you posted with the button inside a `div`: http://jsfiddle.net/v97e8o5e/

Comment: Please put as much of your code in a fiddle then

Comment: Your code works fine http://jsfiddle.net/qmmt64db/ - you need to create a minimal example which reproduces the problem. I would guess that you have a markup validation problem which could be causing the issue.

Comment: also it would be a lot more efficient to give your button an id and then target it with $('#id')

Comment: adding type="button" doesn't help

Comment: what's a markup validation problem? i'll put more code in a fiddle

Comment: invalid markup is when for example you have your markup tags nested incorrectly or don't close your tags correctly. When you have loaded your page, right click and "view page source", copy and paste the contents of your page source into this website and see what errors are reported. http://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input

Comment: all i get in the validator is some stuff about images not having an alt attribute which i fixed now, although it's irelevant, right ...

Answer (score -3):

I would not use button for this function. Maybe you should try this:

1.

HTML

```
<button onclick='clicked'>Click me</button>
```

jQuery

```
function clicked(){
    $("#abc").toggle();
}
```

OR

2.

HTML

```
<div class = 'button'>Click me</div>
```

jQuery

```
$(".button").click(function(){
    $("#abc").toggle();
});
```

---

Hope this helps!

Comment: Based on what do you propose this mess as a solution?